# Need to split date time into two separate field using awk

Tags: awk, split

I have the following awk command and output to convert a DAT file into CSV with specific FS but I would like the fields that contain date time value split into two separate fields plus add :00 seconds in time format.

awk command:

`awk 'BEGIN{FS="\024"; OFS = ","; ORS = "\n"} {gsub(/\376/, "\"", $0); print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' input.dat > output.csv`

input

`þNUMþþDATE CREATEDþþDATE SENTþþDATE MODIFIEDþþDATE RECEIVEDþ
þNUM00000001þþþþ9/11/2017 12:00 AMþþ6/16/2018 12:00 AMþþþ
þNUM00000002þþþþ5/2/2016 12:00 AMþþ6/16/2018 12:00 AMþþþ`

output:

`"NUM","DATE CREATED","DATE SENT","DATE MODIFIED","DATE RECEIVED"
"NUM00000001","","9/11/2017 12:00 AM","6/16/2018 12:00 AM",""
"NUM00000002","","5/2/2016 12:00 AM","6/16/2018 12:00 AM",""`

desired output:

`"NUM","DATE CREATED","CREATED TIME","DATE SENT","SENT TIME","DATE MODIFIED","MOD TIME","DATE RECEIVED","RECEIVED TIME"
"NUM00000001","","","9/11/2017","12:00:00 AM","6/16/2018","12:00:00 AM","",""
"NUM00000002","","","5/2/2016","12:00:00 AM","6/16/2018","12:00:00 AM","",""`

Is there a code I can add per field to perform the split? Note that some lines/rows can be NULL for date/time.

Comment: Thanks @John1024 - updated initial question above with input

Comment: The `þ` is 0x24 ? You can use `gsub` on specific fields, extract the fields and output them. There is even `split` in awk, where you could just split the $5 field on spaces

Comment: @KamilCuk - no that's comma delim char not displayed which is DC4, þ is 376

Comment: If the input is just stable, you could just preparse it with `sed`. `sed -E 's/([0-9\/]{9}) ([0-9:]{4}) ([AP]M)/\1\024\2:00 \3/g'`

Comment: pluse-uno for adding data, current output, required output after a comment! Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on sample data, The datestime need to be split by the first space into date and time. You can use awk functions. For example:

```
awk '
  # Get Date
function get_d (v) {
  sep = index(v, " ")
  return substr(v, 1, sep-1) "\"" ;
}
   # Get Time
function get_t (v) {
  sep = index(v, " ")
  if ( !sep ) return ""
  # insert :00 to time.
  tt= substr(v, sep+1, 5) ":00" substr(v, sep+6)
  # Remove leading zero from hour.
  sub("^0", "", tt)
  return "\"" substr(v, sep+1, 5) ":00" substr(v, sep+6)
#  return "\"" substr(v, sep+1, 99) ;

}

BEGIN {FS="\024"; OFS = ","; ORS = "\n"}
{gsub(/\376/, "\"", $0);
  print $1, get_d($9), get_t($9), get_d($10), get_t($10), get_d($11), get_t($11), get_d($12), get_t($12)}
' input.dat > output.csv
```

Comment: thank you @dash-o, this appear to work though I'm trying to figure out how seconds can be added in for time

Comment: also where a field is NULL, seems to be adding unexpected quotes, comma

Comment: Given no seconds in the input, you can append :00 to the time for the second attribute. get_t above modifeid to add null check, add :00 to returned value

Comment: One final question, how would i account for time format where it doesn't have 2 digit for hours e.g.

`4:15 PM` vs `12:00 AM`

Comment: In 'get_t', you can check if the result time string matches with '0[0-9]', and remove the leading '0' in this case

Comment: not sure i follow, does this mean i'll need to find a way to add another if statement to check for rows with or without 2 digit?

Comment: Answer extended to remove 0 prefix from time. I'm not able to test.

Comment: Almost there. After making a few tweaks from yours I still wind up with this space when time (hour) have only 1 digit. 

Here's the result and notice 1st row with 1 digit hour.
 
`"ControlNum","Group Num","Name","SystemCreateDate","Creat:00edtime"
"AP-000000001","AP-000000001","","6/13/2016","4:15 :00PM"
"AP-000000002","AP-000000002","","12/13/2016","11:15:00 PM"`